# Concatenate an array of strings to a JSONB array of strings without duplicates in PostgreSQL

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, sql-update, jsonb

In PostgreSQL, I have a table named `users` with data that looks like so:

| id | favorites |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `{ "shapes": ["Triangle", "Square"] }` |
| 2 | `{ "shapes": ["Rectangle", "Triangle"] }` |
| ... | ... |

Where `favorites` is a `JSONB` column.

I want to add shapes "Rectangle" and "Circle" to all users' favorite shapes but **without duplication**. The output table should look like so:

| id | favorites |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `{ "shapes": ["Triangle", "Square", "Rectangle", "Circle"] }` |
| 2 | `{ "shapes": ["Rectangle", "Triangle", "Circle"] }` |
| ... | ... |

How do I do that in **one query**?

Limitations:

- The `favorites` object contains other fields than `shapes` and therefore cannot be converted into an array of strings.
- The update must be in one query
- If the input array contains an element that is already in a row's `shapes` array, it must append only the ones that are not already in `shapes`.

Comment: Is this codegolf? First time I see a requirement such as "the update must be in one query"

Comment: It is not codegolf, it is a real requirement for an enterprise application that has the exact limitations above. I obviously stripped out the enterprise schema and replaced it with a more generic table design.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using [`jsonb_set`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-json.html) and the operator `||`, but before insert any data we need to check if it is already in the array or not, to do so we can use the operator `@>` :

```
update mytable
  set favorites = case 
         when favorites->'shapes' @> '["Square"]' = false
              and favorites->'shapes' @> '["Circle"]' = false
              then jsonb_set(favorites, '{shapes}', (favorites->'shapes') || '"Square"'::jsonb || '"Circle"'::jsonb)
         when favorites->'shapes' @> '["Square"]' = false and favorites->'shapes' @> '["Circle"]' = true
              then jsonb_set(favorites, '{shapes}', (favorites->'shapes') || '"Square"'::jsonb)
         when favorites->'shapes' @> '["Square"]' = true and favorites->'shapes' @> '["Circle"]' = false
              then jsonb_set(favorites, '{shapes}', (favorites->'shapes') || '"Circle"'::jsonb)
         else favorites
       end
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Uysr5MfG)

This is an other solution more readable using `jsonb_array_elements` and `jsonb_agg` to make sure the new added elements not exists :

```
with cte as (
  select id as new_id, jsonb_set(favorites, '{shapes}', jsonb_agg(distinct e)) as new_favourites
  from mytable, jsonb_array_elements(favorites-> 'shapes' || '"Square"'::jsonb || '"Circle"'::jsonb) as e
  group by id, favorites
)
Update mytable
SET favorites = new_favourites
FROM cte
where id = new_id
```

[Demo 2 here](https://dbfiddle.uk/dbJBOBlL)

Comment: It's a bit lengthy and brute force-y and will not scale if the list of shapes to add contains ten or more strings. Do you have a more readable and scalable solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH 
step1 as (
  SELECT id,UNNEST(
        ARRAY[json_array_elements_text(favorites::json->'shapes')] ||
        ARRAY['Rectangle','Circle']  -- your parameters here, can be expanded arbitarily
      ) as myfavorites
   FROM test
  ), 
step2 as (
    SELECT 
    test.id, array_agg(DISTINCT step1.myfavorites) as uniquevalues
    FROM test
    INNER JOIN step1 on test.id=step1.id
    GROUP BY test.id
),
step3 as (
    SELECT id as up_id, json_build_object('shapes',uniquevalues) as f
    FROM step2
)
UPDATE test
SET favorites=favorites || f::jsonb
FROM step3
WHERE id=up_id;
```

Instead of the update, you can use for example `"SELECT * FROM step1"` to see what happens at each step.

Step1: Unnest the shapes, and concat them with the parameters

Step2: Keep only distinct

Step3: Rebuild the json property

Update step: Update just the property needed, without harming any other properties you may have stored in that column (credits: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/295300/246773)

Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/8340